# Make an integration between React and Laravel using CSRF token

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, api, csrf

I have an application all built in Laravel, my pages are built using the blade files. But now i have to migrate my front-end to React and i'm having problems migrating the login form.
In my login.blade.html I use the `@CSRF` notation to authenticate the form login, just like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" id="login-form">
  @csrf
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label">E-mail*</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label">Senha*</label>
           <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" />
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12">
        <div class="d-block d-sm-flex  align-items-center">
           <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
                 @lang('home.remember-login')
              </label>
           </div>
           <a href="{{ route('password.request') }}" class="ml-auto">Esqueceu a senha ?</a>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12 mt-3" style="z-index:2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase g-recaptcha" 
           data-sitekey="{{env('RECAPTCHA_CLIENT_KEY')}}" 
           data-callback='onSubmit' 
           data-action='login'>@lang('home.login')</button>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12  mt-3">
        <p>Ainda não tem conta?<a href="/register"> Registrar</a></p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I created an API where i can send a POST request to laravel from React but i still don't know how i can use the same `@CSRF` authentication using the API and not from the blade file. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried using Laravel sanctum? It can authenticate SPA project using session authentication.

Comment: No, i havent't.
I tried to use Laravel/Passport but i don't know if the access token I receive using this library would work like CSRF

Answer (score 1):

You can create a meta-tag and put the csrf value 'csrf_token()' in an attribute, and then retrieve if in java-script code.

in your blade:

```
<meta id ="meta_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

in your js script:

```
let token = document.getElementById('meta_token').getAttribute('content');

//Rest of code
```